# How to fix GNOME Terminal cursor in awesome?

Tags: gnome-terminal, awesome

I'm using awesome 3.4.11 on Ubuntu 12.04, and my default terminal is GNOME Terminal 3.4.1.1. After starting several terminals, it seems the cursor behavior gets disconnected from window focus in some of them:

- Doesn't blink when the window has focus
- Blinks even when the window doesn't have focus

It doesn't seem to be reproducible. I currently have four terminals open on one screen. Two of them work as expected (cursor starts blinking when the window receives focus, reverts to a static rectangle when changing focus), while two of them have constantly blinking cursors. All terminals work fine with regards to keyboard input when focused. `reset` doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

This is [a known issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677329).

It looks like there is a patch that is in progress, but as of this writing has not yet been applied to any Linux distributions.

Comment: Alright. I'll wait to accept until the bug is fixed or some superior solution is presented (unlikely).

Comment: FYI: The bug was fixed in gtk-3.18.9.